# How to use a variable from a make file to an xsl file?

Tags: xslt, makefile, environment-variables

How can I use a variable from a make file in a xsl file , the make file is initiating some executions on the xsl file, it is possible to create something like a environment variable? I want to use it like this:

```
t.mak:
color := red

t.xsl:
<xsl:variable name="MyColor"><xsl:value-of select="color"/></xsl:variable>
```

Comment: You should be able to use an [`xsl:param`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#variables) to pass the value in when the stylesheet is invoked.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work for me , because I invoke it with a java.exe , I am looking more for something like a environment variable or to go in the make file from xsl

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use with java.exe? With Saxon 9 you can read evironment variables using https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-environment-variable

Comment: jre6u45 java.exe org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process (it does a xml to C)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/commandline.html suggests you can pass parameters to the stylesheet (where you have e.g. `<xsl:param name="foo"/>` globally and use it with e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="$foo"/>`) on the command line with

```
java org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process -PARAM foo bar
```